# How to change Bool value within a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reference, boolean

Based on this tutorial: [link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/passing-javascript-function-arguments-by-reference.html#fbid=YjTaEsXxKWP)

Here is my example code:

```
function modifyVar(obj, val) {
  obj.valueOf = obj.toSource = obj.toString = function(){ return val; };
}

function setToFalse(boolVar) {
  modifyVar(boolVar, 'false');
}

var isOpen = true;
setToFalse(isOpen);
console.log('isOpen ' + isOpen);
```

How can I change the bool variable value within a function?
Is it possible to pass the bool value by reference?
thanks in advance

Comment: No way. In javascript scalar parameters (such as boolean) are passed to function **by value**. So you cannot change external variable inside function. But you can return new value from the function and use it to change the variable outside of function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Several problems there:

1. `'false'` is not `false`.
2. Variables are passed **by value** in JavaScript. Always. So there is no connection whatsoever between the `boolVar` in `setToFalse` and the `isOpen` you're passing into it. `setToFalse(isOpen)` is processed like this:

   - The value of `isOpen` is determined
   - That *value* (completely disconnected from `isOpen`) is passed into `setToFalse`
3. JavaScript has some interesting handling around primitive types: If you try to use them like object types (`var a = 42; a.toFixed(2);` for instance), the value gets promoted to a temporary object, that object is used, and then the object is discarded. So if `obj` is `false`, `obj.anything = "whatever"` ends up being a no-op, because the object that temporarily exists ends up getting released as soon as the line finishes.

You could do something *like* what you're doing by promoting `isOpen` to an object via `new Boolean`, but **beware that it will then act like an object, not a boolean**:

```js
function modifyVar(obj, val) {
  obj.valueOf = obj.toSource = obj.toString = function(){ return val; };
}

function setToFalse(boolVar) {
  modifyVar(boolVar, false);
}

var isOpen = new Boolean(true); // An object
setToFalse(isOpen);
snippet.log('isOpen ' + isOpen);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

That works because the value in `isOpen` is a reference to an object. So when that value is passed into `setToFalse` as `boolVar`, `boolVar`'s value is a copy of that reference, and so refers to the same object. So that sorts out issue #2 above. Issue #3 is solved by creating an object explicitly, rather than relying on the implicit behavior.

**But**, remember my warning above about how it will act like an object (because it is one), not like a boolean? Here's an example:

```js
function modifyVar(obj, val) {
  obj.valueOf = obj.toSource = obj.toString = function(){ return val; };
}

function setToFalse(boolVar) {
  modifyVar(boolVar, false);
}

var isOpen = new Boolean(true); // An object
setToFalse(isOpen);
snippet.log('isOpen ' + isOpen);
if (isOpen) {
  snippet.log("isOpen is truthy, what the...?!");
} else {
  snippet.log("isOpen is falsey");
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

We see:

```
isOpen false
isOpen is truthy, what the...?!
```

...because `isOpen` contains a non-null object reference, and non-null object references are always *truthy*.

Comment: Great answer I learned a lot! But What I should do If I would like to check the isOpen value in the if statement?

Comment: Okey I find it... I need to use the valueOf() method in the if statement. thanks

Comment: What if you do it like

    var changeBool = function(obj,prop,value){
      obj[prop] = value;
    }
    var sampleObj = {someBool : true};
    changeBool(sampleObj,'someBool',false);
    console.log(sampleObj.someBool);

Can someone compare the difference between the accepted and this?

Answer (score 8):

We can use that.

```
var myBoolean = { value: false }

//get
myBoolean.value;

//set
myBoolean.value = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing boolean primitive variable `isObject`. For primitive types it doesn't make sense to try to set `toString` method, because it's not needed (and used), since in ECMAScript spec there are already defined rules for [to String conversion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8).

If you really want to use `modifyVar` function like you are trying, you can work with Boolean object instead of primitive:

```
function modifyVar(obj, val) {
  obj.valueOf = obj.toSource = obj.toString = function(){ return val; };
}

function setToFalse(boolVar) {
  modifyVar(boolVar, 'false');
}

var isOpen = new Boolean(true);
setToFalse(isOpen);
console.log('isOpen ' + isOpen);
```

So the answer: use `new Boolean(true)` or `Object(true)`.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure but you are assigning false in single quote, value withing single/double quotes will be considered as string. Just use modifyVar(boolVar, false); and try.